# How to 301 redirect with htaccess URL php variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have to move permanent 301 link to new one but I have some problems with my htaccess file where I have rewriterules.

I have

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*)/kat,([0-9a-z]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)$ index.php?section=catalog&make=show&link=$2&lang=$1&cat=$3&depth=$4&page=$5 [L]
```

web is working on that and i have links like:

```
www.web.com/en/page_name/cat,5,1,1
```

and now i need to make 301 from

```
www.web.com/en/page_name/cat,5,1,1
```

to

```
www.web.com/en/new_name/cat,6,1,1
```

I was trying redirectmatch, redirect and some rewriterule but with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*)/kat,5,1,1$ /$1/$2/kat,6,1,1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*)/kat,([0-9a-z]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)$ index.php?section=catalog&make=show&link=$2&lang=$1&cat=$3&depth=$4&page=$5 [L]
```